# jQuery Slider Previous Button Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

why this previous button isn't working? what i am doing wrong? I am totally new in jQuery! For that reason I can not find bug. And even i don't understand what is the next button doing and how the argument is working! Can anyone help me figure it out? Thank you.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>The slider</title>
<style>
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
body{width: 800px;margin: 100px auto 0;}


#slider-nav{display: none;margin-top: 1em;}
#slider-nav button{
    padding: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider{
    width: inherit;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.slider ul{
    width: 10000px;
    list-style: none;
}

.slider li{float: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="img/img2.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="img/img3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="img/img4.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="slider-nav">
    <button data-dir="prev">Previous</button>
    <button data-dir="next">Next</button>
</div>



<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>(function ( $  ) {
var sliderul=$("div.slider").css("overflow","hidden").children("ul"),
    imgs=sliderul.find("img"),
    imgWidth=imgs[0].width,
    imgsLen=imgs.length,
    current=1,
    totalImgsWidth=imgsLen*imgWidth;


$("#slider-nav").show().find("button").on("click",function(){
    var direction=$(this).data("dir"),
        loc=imgWidth; //800

    // update the current 
    (direction==="next") ? ++current : --current;

    //if first image

    if( current === 0) {
        current = 4;
        loc=totalImgsWidth;
        direction === "next";


    } else if ( current - 1 === imgsLen) {
        current=1;
        loc = 0;
    }
    transition(sliderul,loc, direction);
});

//container what are we manuplating ! It's probably sliderul ! 
function transition( container,loc, direction){
    var unit;

    if(direction && loc !== 0){
        unit= (direction === "next") ? "-=" : "+=";
    }

    container.animate({
       "margin-left": unit ? (unit + loc):loc
    })
}
})(jQuery);</script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works fine can you check console for error?

Comment: its working fine form me also did u include the jquery ?

Comment: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6jx5q82d/1/ what exactly is not working?

Comment: the previous button doesn't go on image 4 when it is on image 1. What's the point?

Comment: and no console error

Comment: can you explain me please ?

Comment: hey, anyone here ?